# KSOAP request in android

Tags: android, ksoap2

My SOAP request format is as follows:

```
 <authentication>
        <LoginID>string</LoginID>
        <Password>string</Password>
      </authentication>
      <Id>int</Id>
      <Str>string</Str>
```

I have to pass the Loginid,pass,id,str as input .So i am setting this through addproperty which is as follows:

```
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                PropertyInfo usrid =new PropertyInfo();
            usrid.setName("LoginID");
            usrid.setValue(userid);
            usrid.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(usrid);        

//          
            PropertyInfo pass =new PropertyInfo();
            pass.setName("Password");
            pass.setValue(password);
            pass.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pass);

                PropertyInfo rote =new PropertyInfo();
            rote.setName("Id");
            rote.setValue(4114616);
            rote.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(rote);
//          
            PropertyInfo dte =new PropertyInfo();
            dte.setName("Str");
            dte.setValue(date);
            dte.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(dte);
```

Is this the correct way i am setting.Because i am receiving the error:

```
 SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server'
  faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
  process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an
  instance of a String.
```

Anybody can please help me.

Comment: Hi , hard code the value of variable first and see the response .

Comment: Hi,i tried that also,it shows the same error.Whether the input setting process is correct in my code.It is possible for some server problem if it how can i know it is server problem.

Comment: go to the server where ur webservice is hosted and open the url of webservice and try to invoke web service from browser

Comment: i went to that url ,in that only the SOAP request and Response format is there,in that how can i invoke the webservices.

Comment: ur web service are on which platform

Comment: I am not pretty well sure about it,i think it is ASP.net.One more thing Mohit Sharma ,in my url 4 webservice methods are there performing different actions,in that in one webservice there is no need to give any input,in that case i have given the url and method name i got the response from that service,also when there is only 1 tag(ie only one input) it also works fine,but wehn there is two r more seperate tags as i given code above(i.e <Authebtication> <id> <string> its not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11176/discussion-between-mohit-sharma-and-subburaj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet to create your soap request:

```
String YOUR_LOGIN_ID = "Your login id";
String YOUR_PASSWORD = "Your password";
int YOUR_ID = 1;
String YOUR_STR = "Your str value";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

SoapObject authentication = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "authentication");
authentication.addProperty("LoginID", YOUR_LOGIN_ID);
authentication.addProperty("Password", YOUR_PASSWORD);

request.addProperty("authentication", authentication);
request.addProperty("Id", YOUR_ID);
request.addProperty("Str", YOUR_STR);
```

Comment: Hi thanks JPriest..i have solved the SOAP fault error by adding ur code..but i am now receiving errorj ava.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize:(that string)..can u please help me.